# How I can copy data from one file in another one

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I created a `form application` and I have two `text files` : `test.txt` and `test2.txt`. I want to copy what is after `=` from `test1.txt`:  `Output="C:\temp\eu.log"` in test2.txt after `=` in `outlog=`.

In `test.txt` I have :

```
Output="C:\temp\eu.log"
```

and in `test2.txt` I have this

```
outlog=
```

and the address of the files is :

```
var link = File.ReadLines(Path + "\\test.txt");
 var link2 = File.ReadLines(Path + "\\test2.txt");
```

How I can do this, without mention the number of line  ?

Comment: Why can't use `File.Copy("C:\\test.txt", "C:\\test2.txt");` ?

Comment: because as you can see I have different name  Output and outlog...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var link = File.ReadLines(path + "\\text.txt").ToArray();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var txt in link)
        {
            if (txt.Contains("Output="))
            {
                var outputPath = txt.Split('=')[1];
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("outlog = {0}", outputPath));

            }
            else if (txt.Contains("Licfile="))
            {
                var LicFilePath = txt.Split('=')[1];
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("license_path = {0}", LicFilePath));
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(path + "\\text2.txt",sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Above code assume the test.txt has first line as the string that needs to be copied to test2.txt which only has "outlog=".

Comment: ok and if i have one more row : in  test.txt  I have Licfile="C:\temp\lic.lic" and in test2.txt  I have license_path=

Comment: You can identify using the first half of the string "Licfile" ,"Output" etc

Comment: Your approach should be based on what restrictions you have, Like if the TextFile is going to have multiple line,Do you want the path to be added one after the other or is it ok to create a completely new output file once all your operations are done.

Comment: If I run your code I have in test2.txt : outlog=
license_path="C:\temp\eu.log""C:\temp\lic.lic", But I want to have : outlog="C:\temp\eu.log"
license_path="C:\temp\lic.lic"

Comment: How about now, I have updated the code so that it overwrites the older one with the values, You can use a similar approach if more config is present.

Comment: This is the answer, that I'm waiting for . Thank you so mach!

Comment: now I observed the fact that, this code rewrite the test2.txt, and I don't want the content of this file to be altered. You can help me in this sens ?

Comment: You can read all the data from existing file in memory and edit parts that you want to update and overrite write all the text back to the file aagain